# How do I know by looking at the Wii game case which type of controllers are necessary/optional and in what quantities?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiimote

I Have a game with a picture of a nunchuck, but it isn't required. Furthermore, it doesn't say how many you CAN use. I was led to believe that to play two players I needed two nunchucks and that wasn't the case. I am trying to avoid this in future purchases and I hope the case has the information on it I need, but I am thinking maybe it is not all provided. For instance, Super Mario Galaxy has a 2 in the Wii-mote and a picture of a nunchuck with no numbers. However, for the second player the nunchuck is not necessary. How are we supposed to know that from the controller graphic in the corner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't just by looking at the case.

Example of a game with multiple optional peripherals: [image]
([Original](http://image.gamespotcdn.net/gamespot/images/box/5/1/8/928518_67606_back.jpg))

Game that requires the Motion Plus and nunchuck: [image]
([Original](http://vgboxart.com/boxes/Wii/38072-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword.png?t=1276820878))

The only way to be 100% certain is to look up the game online and double check.